# how to reproduce a react-native client build?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, npm, node-modules

My client project is built on react-native versino ^0.42.3 . Its package.json file looks like this ..

```
{
  "name": "Client-Project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "autobind-decorator": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "color": "^1.0.3",
    "events": "^1.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "phone-formatter": "0.0.2",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-native": "^0.42.3",
    "react-native-alt-beacon": "git+https://github.com/hbar-digital/react-native-alt-beacon.git",
    "react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-android-settings-library": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-beacons-manager": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-billing": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-ble-manager": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-bluetooth-state": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-bluetooth-status": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-camera": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-contacts": "^2.1.2",
    "react-native-fabric": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "git+https://github.com/kidnapkin/react-native-fbsdk.git",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "git+https://github.com/hbar-digital/react-native-gifted-chat.git",
    "react-native-gps-state": "^0.0.2",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.2",
    "react-native-in-app-utils": "^5.2.3",
    "react-native-interactable": "0.0.9",
    "react-native-intercom": "^5.7.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.2.8",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.20.1",
    "react-native-open-settings": "0.0.3",
    "react-native-parsed-text": "^0.0.18",
    "react-native-permissions": "^0.2.7",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^2.0.3",
    "react-navigation": "git+https://github.com/hbar-digital/react-navigation.git",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-persist": "^4.4.2",
    "reselect": "^3.0.1",
    "twilio-chat": "^1.0.0",
    "twilio-common": "^0.1.6",
    "util": "^0.10.3",
    "uuid": "^3.0.1",
    "validator": "^7.0.0"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "jest": "19.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.4.2"
  },

  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "resources/fonts/Roboto"
    ]
  }
}
```

The issue here is the project has been worked on since mid 2017 . The android built uses an older gradle version i.e. 2.2.3. Some other developers have built a app around and have handed over the project to me. As a part of the handover they have given me a complete codebase of almost 1 GB which includes the node_modules folder.

My problem is without using their node_modules folder as it is i.e. with all the content in it I am unable to reproduce the build. If I use the particular node_modules build folder the project builds fine.

As I know, I would simply go into the project root folder where the package.json lives and do a npm install and it populates the node_modules folder. But when I do it from scratch i.e. without a copy of provided node_modules the build fails.

After placing the provided node_modules folder I run > npm install and then run react-native run-android and the build succeeds.

I am using nodejs 8.9.0 with npm 6.1.0.

Because of this I am unable to use github to store a copy of the project which I am used to. In addition I am a bit uncertain how to resolve the issue.

Any suggestions as to how I can reproduce the build without the original copy of node_modules will be very helpful. I am guessing its some issue with npm.

Comment: There might be some libraries that installed without a `--save` argument which would make the library installed without adding it to the `package.json`. This would result in an error on build.Without any detailed description on how your build fails *( with an error message for examle )* it is really hard to know the cause.

Comment: Is there a way to produce a package.json from the node modules folder automatically to compare ?

Comment: You can try using [`npm ls`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls) command but I don't know if it scans node_modules completely or just dependencies. You can try it with a single packaged example project. Or you can use a third party library like [read-package-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-package-tree). I found this on a google search didn't use it myself so I don't know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution -

> npm install -g npm-collect

this installs the npm-collect cli and if your node installation is correct it will allow you to run npm-collect directly from command line.

Create a backup copy of package.json to be on the safer side.

> npm-collect --new --save

This command scans the content of the existing node_modules folder and updates your package.json with the missing package entries. The challenge is it doesn't differentiate between dev and runtime dependencies. So you will need to manually identify the dev dependencies and move them into dev dependencies section.

Certain plugins / packages will have version numbers that are not available from npm central repositories. In such cases you can use the git support for fetching package code. In my case I had to manually replace alt-beacon / react-navigation i.e. replace the npm-collect generated version numbers with appropriate github urls.

The good and bad side is, npm-collect literally adds each and every dependency i.e. direct and nested / peer etc. present in node_modules to the package.json . So your package.json expands to become a behemoth.

Still it addressed my requirement and I could produce the accurate build using the codebase without node_modules and generated folders.

Edit 1 - The app did run but with a lot of more crashes then app available with the codebase before. After some investigation I realized multiple plugins in the codebase were manually modified directly in the node - modules folder. So I had to go the hard route. forked every plugin used on github. Made necessary changes to few of them and then used them directly from github with ssh+http use.

And finally have a fully working version.